# Why am i getting "Name Error : name x is not defiened" in this program?

Tags: python

```
# UNQ_C2
# GRADED FUNCTION: compute_gradient
def compute_gradient(x, y, w, b): 
 """
    Computes the gradient for linear regression 
    Args:
      x (ndarray): Shape (m,) Input to the model (Population of cities) 
      y (ndarray): Shape (m,) Label (Actual profits for the cities)
      w, b (scalar): Parameters of the model  
    Returns
      dj_dw (scalar): The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameters w
      dj_db (scalar): The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameter b     
 """
    
# Number of training examples
n = x.shape[0]
    
# You need to return the following variables correctly
dj_dw = 0
dj_db = 0
    
### START CODE HERE ###     
    
for i in range (n):
            
        f_wb = w*x[i] + b
        
        dj_db_i = f_wb - y[i]
        
        dj_db += dj_db_i
    
        dj_dw_i = (f_wb - y[i]) * [i]
        
        dj_dw += dj_dw_i 
        
        dj_dw = dj_dw / m
        dj_db = dj_db / m
    
### END CODE HERE ### 
        
return dj_dw, dj_db
```

I was trying to run this code of compute gradient dj/wb, dj/db and I was getting the Name Error: name X is not defined in this program if anyone is having a solution to my problem thay can post it below.

I will be really thankful if anyone will be able to solve my problem, I am stuck on this problem from the past few days.

Comment: You need to indent all the code within the function

Answer (score 0):

Here, x must be your input which you have not specified anywhere. When you try to do a shape on something that has not even been set up/defined yet you encountered this error. Try something like assigning x = your_input_array/matrix etc before you do a shape on it.

Comment: If you have defined x somewhere else and just want to check its shape within the compute_gradient function then clearly its your indentation that is giving the issue